# What is the difference between a web cache and a hierarchial cache server?

Tags: proxy, nat, cache

I'm trying to make sense of how to set up the *simplest possible thing that could actually work* at my office where we host events and have lots of people coming, potentially everyone downloading the same files.

We just bought a small linux server that we figured should be allowed to do DHCP for two network segments and some amount of caching.

I'm thinking of using http://trafficserver.apache.org/ from an excellent answer off of this forum - I think it could suit my simple requirements - but I'm a bit confounded in what configuration I should put it. The [documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TS/FAQ#FAQ-forwardproxy) talks about not exposing a public proxy (I don't want that) and then also about different [modes of operation](http://trafficserver.apache.org/docs/v2/admin/#TrafficEdgeDeploymentOptions) - which should I pick given that I want large files downloaded repeatedly though this NAT-server to be cached with the correct e-tag/cache-policy handling?

Comment: This is a good question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both appear to share most of the same configuration and setup.

The major difference simply seems to be setting up the peer relationships to establish the hierarchy.

So basically the only differences it that ICP (Internet Cache Protocol) is configured in a hierarchy.

Unless you have thousands of computers, or an upstream provider that has a ICP capable proxy that you want to use, then you probably don't have to worry about a hierarchy.